# Python update multiple lines after print

Tags: python, tput

How can I update multi lines in python after print them?

Like this example:

[image]

Something like `tput` ( https://linux.die.net/man/1/tput ) inside python.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this interests you, but you could use a GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the package `rich`? I believe it can do something like what you want.

https://github.com/willmcgugan/rich

Comment: @K.CI For Downloads `rich` looks perfect, thanks, however, my idea was to have a solution to print in any coordinate X, Y in console, like `tput`, Download progress was just an example

Comment: I see. I was thinking not only about the progress bar, but also Live Display (https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/live.html). I guess that would limit you to whatever space you reserved for it, though. If you want something closer to `tput`, then I'm afraid I can't help you at the moment.

Comment: Perfect! I'll try this! Thanks :) (I ran this example: `python -m rich.live`, and is this what I want)